# How Do I Find the FHIR Starter Tutorials?

Tags: hl7-fhir

On the [HL7 Wiki](http://wiki.hl7.org/index.php?title=FHIR_Starter) I found instructions for how to obtain tutorials. Those instructions led me to [here](https://gforge.hl7.org/gf/project/fhir/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=%2Ftrunk%2F) on the HL7GForge site. However, at that location (SVN -> trunk) there is not a "presentations" folder as referred to by the instructions.

Can anyone advise me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presentations folder has been moved to Github.  (Eventually everything in SVN will go there.)  https://github.com/FHIR/documents/tree/master/presentations

Comment: Thank you, Lloyd.